# Not enough button space in Nav Bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I am using the Navigation bar and I am putting in a button, which has a background color. The button looks large in the editor but is very small when I run the program. I tried adjusting the width and it does not let me set constraints, so I am stumped on how to make a larger button in the Navigation bar.

Comment: Are you looking at the wrong size class in interface builder? Similarly have you set the constraints for a specific size class and not "all"?

Comment: I believe I have everything in the right spot. I have one Right-Bar-Button item with one button in it. In the Size Inspector, I set the Right-Bar-Button size to be 14, where it was zero before. I also have the button width to be noticeably large but it shows up as small. @anders

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Edit the values in the size inspector tab.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: When I put a view into the Bar Button Item, it shows up enormous